# How to drop rows by list in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Now I have dataframe and list.

```
A B
1 a 
2 b
3 c
4 d
5 e
```

`list=[a,b,c]`

I would like to drop rows by df.B refering to list.

I would like to below df

```
A B
4 d
5 e
```

How can I get this result?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with inverted mask by `~`.

I think `list` is not good name in `python`, better is `L`, because `list` is code word and if assign variable you override it:

```
L= ['a','b','c']

print (df[~df.B.isin(L)])
   A  B
3  4  d
4  5  e
```

Comment: One might also add `.reset_index(drop=True)`.