# try to delete some data in a column using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

im trying to remove some of the data in my `world_rank` column. Below are how i done it.

here preview:

```
     world_rank                        university_name  \
0             1                     Harvard University   
1             2     California Institute of Technology   
2             3  Massachusetts Institute of Technology   
3             4                    Stanford University   
4             5                   Princeton University   
...         ...                                    ...   
2598    601-800                    Yeungnam University   
2599    601-800            Yıldız Technical University   
2600    601-800               Yokohama City University   
2601    601-800           Yokohama National University   
2602    601-800                     Yuan Ze University   

                       country  teaching international  research  citations  \
0     United States of America      99.7          72.4      98.7       98.8   
1     United States of America      97.7          54.6      98.0       99.9   
2     United States of America      97.8          82.3      91.4       99.9   
3     United States of America      98.3          29.5      98.1       99.2   
4     United States of America      90.9          70.3      95.4       99.9   
...                        ...       ...           ...       ...        ...   
2598               South Korea      18.6          24.3      10.9       26.5   
2599                    Turkey      14.5          14.9       7.6       19.3   
2600                     Japan      24.0          16.1      10.2       36.4   
2601                     Japan      20.1          23.3      16.0       13.5   
2602                    Taiwan      16.2          17.7      18.3       28.6   

     income total_score  num_students  student_staff_ratio  \
0      34.5        96.1       20152.0                  8.9   
1      83.7          96        2243.0                  6.9   
2      87.5        95.6       11074.0                  9.0   
3      64.3        94.3       15596.0                  7.8   
4         -        94.2        7929.0                  8.4   
...     ...         ...           ...                  ...   
2598   35.4           -       21958.0                 15.3   
2599     44           -       31268.0                 28.7   
2600   37.9           -        4122.0                  3.7   
2601   40.4           -       10117.0                 12.1   
2602   39.8           -        8663.0                 20.6   

     international_students female_male_ratio  year  
0                       25%               NaN  2011  
1                       27%      33 : 67 : 00  2011  
2                       33%           37 : 63  2011  
3                       22%          42:58:00  2011  
4                       27%          45:55:00  2011  
...                     ...               ...   ...  
2598                     3%          48:52:00  2016  
2599                     2%           36 : 64  2016  
2600                     3%               NaN  2016  
2601                     8%           28 : 72  2016  
2602                     4%          43:57:00  2016  

[2603 rows x 14 columns]
```

then i try to remove below data:

```
data.drop(["201-225","226-250","251-275","276-300","350-400","301-350","351-400","401-500","501-600","601-800"], inplace = True )
```

but this kind of error showed:

```
KeyError: "['201-225' '226-250' '251-275' '276-300' '350-400' '301-350' '351-400'\n '401-500' '501-600' '601-800'] not found in axis"
```

so, someone could help me with this. You can get the dataset here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ozF5tX-JAWyy3YQd6_MbgsrGYDmi_W5_/view?usp=sharing

p/s: im new to phyton and btw im still students

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to drop rows by list in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41934584/how-to-drop-rows-by-list-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may set the index with the `world_rank`, and then it will work fine:

```
data.set_index('world_rank', inplace = True)
data.drop(["201-225","226-250","251-275","276-300","350-400","301-350","351-400","401-500","501-600","601-800"], inplace = True )

#If you want, you can reset the index to the standard:
data.reset_index(inplace = True)
```

Note: I checked the original dataset, and there are two other segments included in there, that you may consider excluding as well: **['201-250', '251-300']**