# How do I drop rows based on multiple values for a column?

Tags: python, pandas

The dataset that I am working with has 5 US territories included under the State column, and I want to remove any row/record that has these 5 territories as the state name. I'm able to remove all the records based on one value:

```
indexNames = df2[df2['state'] == 'District of Columbia'].index
df2.drop(indexNames , inplace=True)
```

but when I do the same thing with multiple:

```
indexNames = df2[(df2['state'] == 'Guam') & (df2['state'] == 'Virgin Islands')].index
df2.drop(indexNames , inplace=True)
```

no changes take place. Is there anyway I can list all 5 in the first statement and have it work?

Edit: I decided to rename all the nonstate territories to nonstate, and then dropped the rows with the value nonstate in the state column using the following code

```
df2['state'] = df2['state'].replace(['District of Columbia','Guam','Mariana 
Islands', 'Puerto Rico', 'Virgin Islands'],'nonstate')

indexNames = df2[df2['state'] == 'nonstate'].index
df2.drop(indexNames , inplace=True)
```

Comment: Make a list of `states` and apply it like it's show in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41934584/how-to-drop-rows-by-list-in-pandas) post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to drop rows by list in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41934584/how-to-drop-rows-by-list-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1):

You could "drop" those rows by filtering them out:

```
df = df[(df["state"]!="Guam") & (df["state"]!="Virgin Islands")]
```

Personally, I would probably use the **isin** method along with the **~** (NOT) operator:

```
exclude = ("Guam", "Virgin Islands", "District of Columbia")
df = df[~(df["state"].isin(exclude))]
```

This lets you use a sequence so you don't have to hard code in your excluded items.

Comment: You should change ```("Guam", "Virgin Islands", "District of Columbia")``` , to  ```["Guam", "Virgin Islands", "District of Columbia"]``` as your aim is to create a ```list```

Comment: @sophods I don't know that the aim _is_ create a `list` specifically. Unless we think the list of US territories is something that will need to be changed during runtime, an immutable sequence like a tuple is just fine.  I often purposely use a tuple to catch myself erroneously trying to change something that should be a "constant".

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `df2.loc(indexNames)` to see if it pulls out the rows you want?

For example make filter (this can be your state names)

```
filt = (df['lname'] == 'Graham') & (df['fname'] == 'Bob')
```

Then apply the filter to the data frame to extract those rows that fit criteria

```
df.loc[filt]
```

Hope this might help